# Cant find a button in react testing library with getByDisplayValueText

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a simple component that has 3 buttons. i want to find the buttons and simulate click by using react testing library. problem is that I cant find the first button in my test by below code. 
considering I have a button with 
`value="All"` 
and the other button has `"completed"` as a text. I can find the second button (i can't change my code for the first button)

```
document.body.innerHTML = `
<button value="All" />
<button>Completed<button/>
<button>in progress<button/>
<span>multi-test</span>
<div>multi-test</div>`;

screen.debug();
screen.debug(screen.getByDisplayValueText('All'));  ---> doesn't work
screen.debug(screen.getByText('Completed'));  ----> works
```

Answer (score 1):

`screen.debug(screen.getByDisplayValueText('All'));  ---> doesnt work`

You have .getByDisplayValue**Text** and should have .getByDisplayValue (without "Text").

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries

```
getByDisplayValue(
  container: HTMLElement,
  value: TextMatch,
  options?: {
    exact?: boolean = true,
    normalizer?: NormalizerFn,
  }): HTMLElement
```